# What is the risk neutral expectiation of an option price given a move in spot?

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, expected-value

Lets say we have a volatility surface for the SPX at time t with spot S. We consequently know the price of some call option at maturity T with strike K. What is the risk neutral expectation of the option price at t+1day, if spot moves 1% ( **E[option price | S*1.01]** ) ?

Comment: Be more specific. What is '1' here, infinitesimal / very small, or 1 month, 1 year?

Comment: Lets say 1 day.

Comment: Why not just use the delta and gamma then?

Comment: Because volatility also moves.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear / lacks relevant detail, but I suspect what you're really asking is what happens to the vol change when the spot change is given.

Assume, as an example, the following dynamics:
\begin{align}
dS_t &= \sigma_t S_t dW_t \\
d\sigma_t &= \alpha \sigma_t ( \rho dW_t + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} dZ_t)
\end{align}
with $dW dZ = 0$.

You'd like to calculate $E_t[ C(S_{t+dt},\sigma_{t+dt},K) | dS_t = c]$. Now
$$
C(S_{t+dt},\sigma_{t+dt},K) = C(S_t,\sigma_t, K) + dC(S_t,\sigma_t,K)
$$
with
$$
dC(S_t,\sigma_t,K) = \Delta dS_t + \nu d\sigma_t
$$
with $\Delta$ the delta of the option and $\nu$ the vega.

Given $dS_t = c$ then
\begin{align}
dS_t &= c\\
d\sigma_t &= \frac{\rho \alpha}{S_t} dS_t + (\cdot) dZ_t \\
& =  \frac{\rho \alpha}{S_t} c + (\cdot) dZ_t
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
E_t[ C(S_{t+dt},\sigma_{t+dt},K) |dS_t = c] &= C(S_t,\sigma_t,K) + c \Delta + \frac{\rho \alpha}{S_t} c \nu + E[ (\cdot) dZ_t] \\
&= C(S_t,\sigma_t,K) + c \Delta + \frac{\rho \alpha}{S_t} c \nu
\end{align}

Comment: The problem now becomes: What is the risk neutral estimate of the spot-vol correlation

Comment: That's a different question but it's well known that correlation is proportional to the ATM slope.

Comment: Well, you framed your answer in a way that left one variable to which we do not know the risk neutral estimate: the spot vol correlation, which should indeed be somewhat proportional to the skew.

Comment: Yeah ok, and you're welcome by the way.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound smug, sorry if was the case, thanks for taking your time to reply.

Comment: No worries at all.

Comment: Assuming considered model, the arguments of @Frido look sound. The correlation is constant and should be determined by the calibration to fit time-$t$ option prices. A time-dependence of correlation would require extension of this example model.